# Test folder outside src for CRA?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, create-react-app

I write test for my application created with `npx create-react-app --template typescript` but I don't know how to save test files, next to a component or in a separate folder `test`?

I think I should to create `test` folder outside `src`:

```
src
- App.tsx 
- ... etc
test
- App.test.tsx 
- ... etc
```

How do it? `npm test` doesn't see tests which are outside `src`.

Also I need tests for redux store, reducers etc., because I cannot save test files next to component, modules (so as not to litter directories).

Comment: CRA is opinionated setup, it expects all source files that are supposed to be transpiled to reside inside src, so it should be src/test. You can either follow the rules, or eject.

Comment: @EstusFlask, so... ok, thanks for your answer